# Specify different repositories when using Cordova gradle wrapper

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, gradlew

I'm using Cordova Android 4.0.0 which uses a gradle wrapper to build.  I need to specify a different repository than mavenCentral.  I can't simply modify the build.gradle file because it's auto-generated by Cordova.  Because it's using the wrapper distribution specified by Cordova I can't add an /init.d to the distribution.  I've tried adding a USER_HOME/.gradle/init.gradle file which doesn't seem to be getting used.  Is there some other way to specify an init file when using a wrapper that I don't have control over?

EDIT:
As a workaround for now I've added an after_prepare hook that changes the text "mavenCentral()" found anywhere in the build.gradle files to the repo I need to use instead.  There's got to be a better gradle based solution though...

Comment: 3 years later, the same basic issue is driving me nuts; my build fails on play-services-auth.jar (can't download from jcenter -- looks to be missing from their server).  Putting `google()` before `jcenter()` in `build.gradle` lets me build.  Looks like I'll need to use that hook, too :\

Answer (score 7):

We use ionic and have our own nexus repository that we use instead of mavenCentral. We ended up creating a hook to resolve this [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9704)

by adding a hook :

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {
    'use strict';
    var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
        path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path'),
        deferral = ctx.requireCordovaModule('q').defer(),
        replaceStream = require('replacestream'),
        async = require('async');
    var platformRoot = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android');
    var gradleFiles = [path.join(platformRoot, 'build.gradle'), path.join(platformRoot, 'CordovaLib', 'build.gradle')];
    async.each(gradleFiles, function(f, cb) {
        fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err);
                return;
            }
            var result = data.replace(/mavenCentral\(\)/g, 'maven{url "http://nexus.corp.aal.au/content/groups/public-ad"}');
            fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', cb);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            deferral.reject();
        } else {
            deferral.resolve();
        }

    });
    return deferral.promise;
}
```

Comment: Somewhat nasty solution but a solution. I used this now to correct the order of jcenter() to google maven repo because jcenter removes jars from their repo if a new version is deployed, leaving an invalid POM of the previous version (example: https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/)

Comment: Thanks for your post!  Recently were some packages that were unpublished from the jcenter repository, so I used your solution in my cordova project as a 'before_build' hook combined with the suggest workaround repo URL in the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment85

Comment: Hi Arun, and thanks for your post. Which kind of hook did you used ? Many many thanks in advance

Comment: @SimoneCampagna Its been a while but I believe it was androidBeforeBuild.js which I put under hooks folder and you need to update config.xml with an entry:
`<hook src="hooks/androidBeforeBuild.js" type="before_build"/>`

Comment: Hi Arun, abs yes! Your 'async' write method save our builder ... until next dependencies problem :D 
Thank you so MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You specify additional Maven repos in the gradle init script https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

Like this:

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { 
            credentials {
                username 'your_user_name'
                password 'your_password'
            }
            url "https://your_repo" 
        }
        maven { url "http://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/" 
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I explained in the question that using an init script was either not an option (for init.d) or not working (init.gradle).

Answer (score 0):

The way this can be made to work seems to change over time. I've been having quite the trouble getting Cordova/Phonegap to behave. This, however, currently works for me:

- Create a `build.gradle` file or copy one from a newly made Android Studio project -- y'know, it likes to put `jcenter()` there by default. Example below.
- Add it to your `plugin.xml` file as a custom "framework" in of type gradleReference in your Android platform tag. Example below.
- While I'm at it -- if you need other gradle changes such as changing the Java language level, you can include a `build-extras.gradle` file as well to tweak the other settings (not sure if these need to be separate honestly but I've gotten to the end of my leash trying to deal with this thing). Example also below. Yes, the target directory has to be `src/..`.

Sample `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.example:some-sdk:2.3.1'
}
```

Sample `plugin.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" id="io.proxsee" version="0.1.0">
    <!-- When you update this file, update the package.json too. -->
    <!-- Reference: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html -->
    <!-- .. other stuff .. -->
    <platform name="android">
        <!-- .. other stuff .. -->
        <framework src="build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
        <source-file src="build-extras.gradle" target-dir="src/.." />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Sample `build-extras.gradle`:

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup/javawriter/pom.xml'
            exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup/javawriter/pom.properties'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should the file "app/build.gradle" have what there is in the custom build.gradle after adding a plugin with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are two `build.gradle` files and IIRC the one I specified is just the root one. The `app/build.gradle` file is a bit different and no, should not contain a copy of what the root one has.

Answer (score 0):

I've built on @arun-gopalpuri's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210134) to add support for adding a custom repository for all plugins in an Android application.

It works by finding all gradle files, and inserting the custom repository above any others (only if it hasn't been already added).

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const async = require("async");

module.exports = context => {
    "use strict";
    const repoUrl = "http://nexus.corp.aal.au/content/groups/public-ad";
    const gradleRepo = 'maven { url "' + repoUrl + '" }';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const platformRoot = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, "platforms/android");

        const gradleFiles = findGradleFiles(platformRoot);

        async.each(
            gradleFiles,
            function(file, callback) {
                let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");

                let insertLocations = [];
                const myRegexp = /\brepositories\s*{(.*)$/gm;
                let match = myRegexp.exec(fileContents);
                while (match != null) {
                    if (match[1].indexOf(repoUrl) < 0) {
                        insertLocations.push(match.index + match[0].length);
                    }
                    match = myRegexp.exec(fileContents);
                }

                if (insertLocations.length > 0) {
                    insertLocations.reverse(); // process locations end -> beginning to preserve indices
                    insertLocations.forEach(location => {
                        fileContents =
                            fileContents.substr(0, location) +
                            gradleRepo +
                            fileContents.substr(location);
                    });

                    fs.writeFileSync(file, fileContents, "utf8");
                    console.log("updated " + file + " to include repo " + repoUrl);
                }

                callback();
            },
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("unable to update gradle files", err);
                    reject();
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            },
        );
    });

    function findGradleFiles(dir) {
        let results = [];
        const list = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        list.forEach(fileName => {
            const filePath = path.join(dir, fileName);
            const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
            if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                // recurse into subdirectory
                results = results.concat(findGradleFiles(filePath));
            } else if (path.extname(filePath) === ".gradle") {
                results.push(filePath);
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
};
```

We're using this in an Android hook:

```xml
<hook src="build/android/useInternalRepo.js" type="before_build" />
```

I've added the same to the outstanding Cordova issue ([CB-9704](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9704)).